# Using different font for same size class and orientation

Tags: ios, fonts, size-classes

I have used story boards to create my view controllers. I have applied auto layouts to all the views and sub views; but the font size is same on all the devices. The only way I know to achieve this is to detect the bounds of the screen and creating the if statement.

```
if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 568) {
    // Assign Font size for iPhone 5
}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 667){
    // Assign Font size for iPhone 6
}
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 736){
// Assign Font size for iPhone 6+
} 
else if ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height == 480){
// Assign Font size for iPhone 4s
}
```

Question: Is there any other way to implement this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Fonts can be set per size class in the storyboard like so:

[image]

When you click the '+' button you are presented with the following:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate the quick response. The problem is that I have my views designed for iPhone 5, I want to resize font size for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus which lie in the same size class category for portrait mode.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry I missed that. Not sure if there is better solution that what you are already doing for that. You could do the check on the device model with ```[[UIDevice currentDevice] model]``` but that doesn't really clean things up much. Wish I had a better answer for you!

Answer (score 1):

If you have used UILabel you can choose **autoshrink** option from storyboard and set min font scale or min font size.hope this would help you.

Comment: Thanks, its going to help me out in half my way !

Is the a fix for UITextfields and UIButtons as well ?

Comment: well if you are using textfield then you can set min font size and select "adjust to fit" but you cannot do much about buttons.